# On Nabi Muhammad’s ﷺ Genealogy

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, family, shia-sunni

I read articles about Nabi Muhammad's ﷺ genealogy and they say that Salma bint Amr is a Jewish woman from Banu Najjar tribe. Sayyid A. Amiruddin said in his website that Banu Najjar is a Jewish clan descended from king Dawud (David) mentioning a hadith attributed to Ja’far al-Sadiq.
Here are the links:
https://sayyidamiruddin.com/2012/12/26/the-house-of-israel-the-royal-house-judah-and-the-royal-house-of-hashem-by-sayyid-ahmed-amiruddin/
[https://raseef22.net/article/1085561-سلمى-جدة-نبي-الإسلام-التي-انشقت-الأرض-وابتلعتها-تاريخيا](https://raseef22.net/article/1085561-%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D9%89-%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4%D9%82%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%B6-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AA%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%A7)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_Muhammad

What is the source of these articles? Who is able to show us a hadith from masdar shia or sunni?

شكرا